# How can i position a layer on an image inside a div container?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fighting with writing a little gallery. There a some thumbs shown next to each other and i want a black layer on these thumbs. Later I want to make the layer transparent and have it animated when hovered over...

[edit]i want the black overly on each image, with the same width and height of the img...so that all the images are totally black

At the moment the black boxes float somewhere but not exactly over the image...

** http://jsfiddle.net/2NXF8/ **

my html looks like this:

```
    <div id ="gallery_container">

        <div class ="image-container">

            <img src="http://polpix.sueddeutsche.com/polopoly_fs/1.394491.1273512871!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/120x120_fit2max/image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class ="image-container">

            <img src="http://polpix.sueddeutsche.com/polopoly_fs/1.394491.1273512871!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/120x120_fit2max/image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class ="image-container">

            <img src="http://polpix.sueddeutsche.com/polopoly_fs/1.394491.1273512871!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/120x120_fit2max/image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>


        <div class ="image-container">

            <img src="http://polpix.sueddeutsche.com/polopoly_fs/1.394491.1273512871!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/120x120_fit2max/image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>


        <div class ="image-container">

            <img src="http://polpix.sueddeutsche.com/polopoly_fs/1.394491.1273512871!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/120x120_fit2max/image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

my css looks like this:

```
#gallery_container{
    width:100%;
}
.image-container{
    /*width:200px;*/
    height:170px;
    float:left;
    width:196px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #a9b0ba;
}
.image-container img{
    width:auto;
    height:170px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay{
   position:absolute;
   height:33%;
   width:33%;
   background-color: black;
   z-index:2;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see its overlaying, do you want to overlay it also on the top image? is that your problem?

Comment: hi thanks for asking i want the overly on each image, with the same width and height of the img...so that all the images are totally black..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modified fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/2NXF8/4/

I had to remove the width:auto from the image, but it's not required anyway.  It wraps the image with a span and then inserts a div after the image, the same size with a black background.

Comment: holy...thats a lot of javascript...and work...thanks a lot! You saved my day!

Comment: You're welcome.  It's actually something I had lying round used for creating overlays on product images with "special offer" or "new product" banners.

Comment: good man! I use it to build a site with responsive design...so sad that touch device dont have a mouseover event...

Comment: I know of 1 that does - the Galaxy Note with the Smart Pen.  You can hover near the screen to trigger mouseover.  Just wait - it'll become normal in time ;)